# Does anyone know a cleaner way to write this regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
(?:reminder|Reminder)\s\d+\s\b(?:second|seconds|Second|Seconds|minute|minutes|Minute|Minutes|hour|hours|Hour|Hours|day|days|Day|Days|week|weeks|Week|Weeks|month|months|Month|Months|year|years|Year|Years)\b
```

Objective format: "Reminder 3 seconds", "Reminder 20 days", "Reminder 3 second" etc

Answer (score 3):

`[rR]eminder\s\d+\s(?:[sS]econd|[mM]inute|[hH]our|[dD]ay|[wW]eek|[mM]onth|[yY]ear)s?\b`

I think this works. Most of the changes I made were putting characters into groups. A little bit of it was moving the sometimes-s outside the group. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Just a little suggestion: you don't need a group for the first part.  `[rR]eminder\s\d+....` will work

Comment: Also the ‘\b‘ before the time unit is superfluous as it is following a ‘\s‘. These should make the regex even shorter

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe less boundaries might be OK here,

```
(?i)\breminder\s+\d+\s+\b(?:seconds?|minutes?|hours?|days?|weeks?|months?|years?)\b
```

or maybe not.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YeoWM/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"(?i)\breminder\s+\d+\s+\b(?:seconds?|minutes?|hours?|days?|weeks?|months?|years?)\b"
string = """
Reminder 3 seconds some data here, Reminder 20 days and some more data, Reminder 3   second and Reminder  3  WEek
"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['Reminder 3 seconds', 'Reminder 20 days', 'Reminder 3   second', 'Reminder  3  WEek']
```

Comment: +1 for making use of case-insensitive .  However it slightly twisted OP's original requirement (e.g. allowing extra spaces, allowing mixed cases etc) which I guess OP needs to clarify if it is desirable

Comment: Matches, for example, ‘seConDs’ in addition to ‘Seconds’. I doubt that is desirable or the OP would not have gone to all the trouble to enumerate all the special cases.